# How fast does the number of integer rectangles grow as a function of their area?

Tags: asymptotics

Suppose we define $R(k)$ as the number of $m \times n$ rectangles with integer sides and area $mn = k$ (we don't distinguish between $m \times n$ and $n \times m$).

How fast does this function grow "on average" and "in the long run"?

Comment: Check out the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Growth_rate)

Comment: Have you considered the cases where $k$ is a prime ? Thus, it is dubious that $R(k+1)/R(k)$ has a limit...

Comment: Yes, I removed that part of the question. I am not sure how to ask the question properly to capture what I really want to know. I looked at the divisor function now, which I guess has the relevant information.